# How to make border of a span overlap border of a relative positioned div?

Tags: css

I want to create a navigation tab using a span element within a nav element as follows:

```
<nav><span>span</span></nav>
<div id=relative>div</div>
```

This navigation tab is placed directly above a div containing the main content. The div is given a relative position so that elements (not shown) within it can be positioned absolutely with respect to it. For simplicity, the following shows the relevant css:

```
span {
    border: black solid 10px;
}
div {
    border: orange solid 10px;
}
#relative {
    position: relative;
}
```

A demonstration in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aexj/) shows the border of div overlapping on top of the border of the span when the former is changed from a static position to a relative position. I tried to reverse it back by given a high z-index, but to no avail. Can anyone show me a solution which doesn't involves introducing new elements or changing the display property of the current elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
span {
    border: black solid 10px;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3aexj/3/

Since it's been chosen as the answer, I thought I'd add a little more:

If you don't change the z-index of an element, it will be based on the order of the element in the page.

A negative margin would still keep the element *under* the one that follows.

"Alright. Let's give the span a z-index, then.
- Go for it!
- It's not working!".

Nope!
To be able to alter an element's z-index, it needs to have a position value other than "static".

Comment: Wow, that's quite smart! Yes, it is what I want. Thanks :)

Comment: My pleasure. To be able to assign a z-index, it has to have a property other than static (default position: ). Since the element you wanted on top comes before the one it should overlap on the page, the default assigned z-index would be "under" the div.